# Deserializing a String with into_serde makes the app panick

Tags: rust, webassembly, serde, serde-json

With a friend of mine, we're trying to use the `serde_json` crate to deserialize some message sent by a WebSocket.

We are having a specific error, and we managed to recreate it with the following snippet of code:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct EffetSer {
    test: String
}

fn main() {
   let test_value = JsValue::from_str("{\"test\": \"value\"}");
   let test_value: EffetSer = test_value.into_serde().unwrap();
   log::error!("WOW : {:?}", test_value);
}
```

Our TOML has the following dependencies:

```
wasm-bindgen = { version = '0.2.63', features = ['serde-serialize'] }
serde = { version = '1.0', features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = '1.0.55'
js-sys = '0.3.40'
```

The error is the following:

```
app.js:310 panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error("invalid type: string \"{\\\"test\\\": \\\"value\\\"}\", expected struct EffetSer", line: 1, column: 23)'
```

Any help would be very appreciated, as we're still struggling to understand what we're doing wrong and why we cannot deserialize our `String`.

Comment: What is `Component`? I can't find it in your dependencies. It would help if you provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I'm sorry I should have put a main. I'm editing my original post right away.

Comment: I believe the issue is with `JsValue`. Because using serde only works just fine: `let eff: EffetSer = serde_json::from_str("{\"test\": \"value\"}").unwrap();`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely misunderstanding of `into_serde`'s semantics.

According to [documentation](https://docs.rs/wasm-bindgen/0.2.68/wasm_bindgen/struct.JsValue.html#method.into_serde), it works like this:

> Invokes JSON.stringify on this value and then parses the resulting JSON into an arbitrary Rust value.

In other words, its semantics are as following:

- convert each component of the `JsValue` to the corresponding `serde` internal element;
- deserialize the required type from the given tree of components.

Now, what does this mean in our case? Well, you created `JsValue` using [`JsValue::from_str`](https://docs.rs/wasm-bindgen/0.2.68/wasm_bindgen/struct.JsValue.html#method.from_str), which, again according to documentation,

> Creates a new JS value which is a string.

So, the `JsValue` here is not an object, as you are likely assuming; it is a primitive - a string, which simply happens to have the shape of object's JSON representation. Then, when you invoke `from_serde`, Serde sees the string - not as input, but as internal representation, which cannot be transformed into object.

---

Now, what to do? There are several ways to fix this code:

1. First and the most obvious: don't use `JsValue` at all, deserialize from `&str` directly with `serde_json::from_str`.
2. Use [js_sys::JSON::parse](https://docs.rs/js-sys/0.3.45/js_sys/JSON/fn.parse.html) to get the object-like `JsValue` from string, and then convert it to the `EffetSer` with `into_serde`. This is likely to be less efficient, since it requires the round-trip of `JSON::parse` and `JSON::serialize` to convert the string to object and then back to string.
3. Write your own method to convert `JsValue` to `EffetSer` directly. I'm not sure if this is possible, however, since I wasn't able to find a way to extract a single field from JS object.